# bokeh, dynamically change plot width

Tags: python, resize, bokeh

I'm trying to change plot width when taptool selects something.
I invoke this using bokeh serve, and navigating to the localhost website

when I click on one of the rectangles, my console prints out "callback" and "callback2" but my plot doesn't change width.
What am I doing wrong?

```
counts = [1*10**7,2*10**7,3*10**7]     #dummy data
l_edge = [x for x in range(len(counts))]
r_edge = [x + .85 for x in range(len(counts))]

data = {
    'height': counts,
    'leftEdges': l_edge,
    'rightEdges': r_edge,
}


p = figure()
s = ColumnDataSource(data)
p.add_tools(TapTool())

def callbackfcn(attr,old,new): 
    global p
    print('callback')
    p.width = np.random.choice([100,200,300,1000,10000])
    p.height = np.random.choice([100,200,300,1000,10000])
    print('callback2')

r = p.quad(top='height',bottom=0,
               left = 'leftEdges',right = 'rightEdges',
              source = s)        

r.data_source.on_change('selected',callbackfcn)              

layout = column(p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instead including sizing_mode in your layout?  Take a look at the [Bokeh docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html) for an example.